# PyQt5 - Unable to get QPushButton to size properly in a QGridLayout

Tags: pyqt5, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

I wanted to get insight into widget resizing behavior I noticed, and it may have to do with wanting to create a set of push buttons in a grid.  Here is a snippet:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QPushButton
)

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 780, 460)
        self.setWindowTitle("Frame with Grid")

        self.gLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.gLayout)

        # Populate some data in grid cells
        row = 0
        for col in range(5):
            pb = QPushButton(str(row) + ", " + str(col))
            #pb.resize(50, 50)
            styleStr = "QPushButton { padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px; }"
            pb.setStyleSheet(styleStr)
            self.gLayout.addWidget(pb, row, col)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The example creates the set  of buttons, but I cannot get the padding on right and left to work as I expect.

I also tried explicitly resizing the PushButton but that too does not have the expected effect.  My assumption is that I am doing something wrong, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Padding doesn't change the widget maximum size, it only tells the style to add a "margin" between the content and the border: if the widget is allowed to expand its size, then it will be shown at its full extent. Try to change to `self.gLayout.addWidget(pb, row, col, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)` (adding `from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt` to the imports), and report if that's what you actually wanted.

Comment: What is the effect you are expecting?

Comment: Use `self.gLayout.setSpacing(20)` and get rid of the stylesheet. For a grid-layout, you can also [set the vertical and horizontal spacing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#horizontalSpacing-prop) independently. For the spacing around the edges of the grid, you can [set the contents margins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins).

Comment: @musicamante: Thanks! I got rid of the stylesheet and added AlignCenter, and that did the trick.  Although I am confused what actually happened behind the scenes, and how the Layout Manager computed the appropriate size.

Comment: @Alexander, I was expecting more spacing between the pushbutton widgets.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I tried what you suggested, and I see spacing between the pushbutton widgets.  By playing with the spacing, I can get the effect I desire.  The net effect is pretty much the same as the solution suggested by musicamante (with the added benefit that no specific experimentation with spacing is needed).  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @lanewsa a lot of things happen behind the scenes: a layout primarily uses the `sizeHint()` and `sizePolicy()` of all child widgets it manages, eventually deciding how to allocate the available size (and even asking its parent widget to increase its size). Most widgets allow the layouts to increase their sizes if there's enough space left, which is the case for horizontal dimensions of buttons: your padding is there, but since the layout has enough space to show larger buttons, you don't see it. You won't be able to horizontally shrink the window beyond the limits of those paddings, though.

Comment: @lanewsa You can try to increase those paddings and try to make the window narrower, then you'll see. By default, using the basic `addWidget()` call, the layout will try to let the widget occupy as much space as possible (if its *size policy* allows that) in the "layout cell", but if you specify the `alignment` flag, then the widget will only take as much space as its size hint suggests. I suggest you to do some research about the above functions, and also do some experiments in Qt designer with different widget types and trying to change their size policies or minimum/maximum sizes.

Comment: @musicamante, Thank you! Your suggestions are invaluable!  I have been able to successfully adjust the size to my liking by following your earlier guidance, but clearly a deeper dive into understanding how layouts work would be very beneficial to me.